# How to access child node of JSON in react? MobileRiskList is list how can we access?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, list

formJson
{
"NTLFee": 0,
"OperationType": "Y",
"MobileLobList": [
{
"GrossPremium": 1227.72,
"MobileCoverageList": [
{
"Vat": 0
}
],
"MobileElementId": 195490042,
"MobileId": 195490040,
"MobileRiskList": [
{
isAppilcable=’Y’
}
]
]

When I am wirting this.form.OperationType == ‘Y’ -> this is working fine
But now,
I want to write condition for isAppilcable in react.
But when I tried this.form.isAppilcable == ‘Y’ -> this is not working as it is child node.

The path is formJson=> MobileLobList => MobileRiskList=> isAppilcable

Can you please help me out how can I access this child node in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path is `formJson.MobileLobList[0].MobileRiskList[0].isAppilcable`.

Both `MobileLobList` and `MobileRiskList` are arrays and you must get the element by index.